# What happens when Git pull or push to different branch being in some other branch

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I am familiar with GIT and using the same for versioning of my project.

I am having few queries which I would like to know. I googled but couldn't get the good answer.

So the thing is I am having **master, module1, feature1** branches.

```
master
 ---------- 
         | module1
         ----------
                  | feature1
                  ------------
```

module1 is branched from master and feature1 is branched from module1.

**Query 1** : Being in feature1 branch what if I work on few changes and commit and push the same to module1.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Changes of feature1"
git push origin module1 //Being in feature1 branch
```

What happens here to the code of feature1 to module1 branch and how module1 branch takes it.

**My Understaing** : As per my understanding the feature1 changes will be pushed to module1 branch. And later I realised that I should have pushed to feature1 branch then I will push the same to feature1 branch and will checkout to module1 branch and revert the code which I had pushed recently.

**Query 2** : What if being in the feature1 branch and I pull the code of module1 in this branch by the following

```
git pull origin module1 //Being in feature1 branch
```

**My Understanding** : The changes of the module1 code will get merged to my feature1 branch and is same as the following in commands

```
git checkout moduel1
git pull origin module1
git checkout feature1
git merge module1
```

If there are any conflicts will be shown. Which I need to resolve.

Can anyone help me whether my understanding is correct or not. If not please help me to understand this concept properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have, I think, a few broad misconceptions about branch names and the use of `git pull`.  Let me split this into several parts, and give you this executive summary overview to start with:

- `push`'s counterpart is not `pull`, it's `fetch`;
- `git pull` just runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge`, and I believe it's best for new Git users to avoid `git pull`, using instead the two separate commands;
- while `push` and `fetch` use names for transferring hash IDs, it's the *commits*, identified by hash IDs, that matter; and
- for `git merge` or `git rebase`, your current branch *does* matter.  During push or fetch, the current branch does not matter, but if you use `git pull`, that runs `git merge` or `git rebase`, and *now* the current branch matters.

Now, let's dive into the details.

#### A branch name is only a pointer to a (single) commit

Git is all about *commits*.  Git would, in a sense, "like it" if us mere humans did not need branch names, and just talked about commits by hash ID all the time.  I might ask you if you are using commit `95ec6b1b3393eb6e26da40c565520a8db9796e9f`, and you would say "yes" or "no, but I have that one" or "no, and I have not heard of that one yet".

You mention that:

> module1 is branched from master and feature1 is branched from module1.

but in Git's eyes, branches don't branch *from* another *branch*.  Instead, each commit links to a previous, or *parent*, commit.  You drew this:

> ```
> master
>  ---------- 
>          | module1
>          ----------
>                   | feature1
>                   ------------
> ```

which suggests to me that you think of commits as belonging to (or being "on") *only one branch*.  That's not how Git sees them, though.  Instead, most commits are on *many branches at the same time*.  For instance, consider a graph that we might draw like this:

```
          o--o--o   <-- br1
         /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--o   <-- br2
```

where each round `o` represents a commit.  All the commits down the middle row are on `master`, but *most* of those commits are *also* on `br1` and `br2`.  The *last* (newest and right-most) commit on `master` is *only* on `master`; the rest are on the other branches as well.

This is all because, in Git, a branch *name* like `master` points only to *one* commit.  The commit to which the name points is the one furthest to the right, if we draw the commit graph this way, left (earlier) to right (later).  Git calls this the *tip* commit, or sometimes the *head* (note lowercase here) of the branch.  To find the rest of the commits that you—or Git—can reach from this tip commit, Git will look up the commit by its big ugly hash ID, such as `95ec6b1...`.  Again, it's the *hash ID* that lets Git find the commit.  The *name* just lets Git find this hash ID!

The commit itself stores a parent commit hash ID, so Git will look up the parent commit by *its* hash ID, finding the commit one step back.  That commit has another parent ID, and so on.  Walking backwards through this sequence of parent hash IDs, one commit at a time, from later to earlier, is how we see `git log`, for instance.

If you run:

```
git checkout br1
```

and then do some work and then run:

```
git add -a && git commit
```

and make a *new* commit—let's draw this as `*` instead of `o` so that we can see it—here's what happens to the branch name `br1`:

```
          o--o--o--*   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--o   <-- br2
```

We draw this with the `(HEAD)` (note: all-uppercase) added to remember which name we gave to `git checkout`.  The *new* commit `*` goes in the graph, and points backwards to whichever commit *was* the tip of `br1`.  Meanwhile Git *changes* the name `br1` so that it points to the new commit we just made.  This is how branches grow, in Git: we add new commits to the graph, and Git updates the *name* that `HEAD` is attached-to.

Of course, it's no accident that if we start at the tips of both `br1` and `master` and work backwards, we'll eventually come back to a single meeting-point commit.  But this confluence of commits doesn't arise from the *names*.  It doesn't matter *how we choose to start from* the tip commit of `br1` and the tip commit of `master`; what matters is *these two particular commits, and then each commit we find along the way*.

The branch names, in other words, get us started in the commit graph.  ***It's the commit graph that matters most.***  The names just serve as starting points!

#### The opposite of `push` is `fetch`

Everything above is about working within a single Git repository.  But when we do work with Git, we work with more than one repository.  In particular, we have *our* repository, where we do our own work, but then we often need to talk with another Git repository stored on some other machine, like those provided by GitHub, or by an employer or a friend or colleague.

This means that we want to *share* commits.  As we saw above, Git is all about the commits and the commit graph—but we mere humans need *names* to get us started.  This is where `git fetch` and its counterpart, `git push`, come in.  Running either command connects our Git to some other Git.

Our Git has all the commits we have, some of which may be commits that we made.  Some of our Git's commits might be commits we got from elsewhere.  Similarly, their Git has all the commits they have, some of which are the same as commits we have.  Some may be different commits.  But in any case, *all* of these commits are identified by their unique hash IDs.  These IDs are the same in *every* Git, all around the world, if they have the same commits.  If they don't have our commits (because we just made them), our new commits have IDs that are different from every commit ID they have!  (This seems like magic, but it's just cryptographic mathematics—some of which is similar to what's behind Bitcoin, for instance, though Git uses a weaker set of hashes.)

In the end, this means that each of these two Gits can tell which commits one of us has that the other doesn't, just by looking at these hash IDs.  That's how our Git can give their commits we have that they don't—`git push`—or their Git can give our Git commits they have that we don't: `git fetch`.

Once they have sent commit objects (and other related Git objects needed to make those commits complete), the two Gits then need to set up *names* for any new *tip* commits.  This is the second place that branch names start to matter.

The fetch direction is simpler.  Your Git calls up some other Git.  Usually we use the name `origin` to stand for some URL, where the other Git is listening for calls, so we run `git fetch origin`.  Your Git calls up that Git, and asks it: *What are your branch tip names?  What hash IDs are those?*  Their Git tells your Git about its branch tips and hash IDs, and your Git either says: *Ah, I have that hash ID* or *Hmm, I don't have that hash ID, please send me that commit, and by the way what's its parent hash ID because maybe I need that one too*, and so on.

Eventually, your Git has all the commit and other hashed objects that they suggested.  Now your Git takes their branch names, like their `master`, and *saves those names*.  But you have your own branches.  Your Git cannot save those names as *your* branches.  It *renames* all those names.  Their branches, like `master`, become your Git's *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/master`.  Note that your Git is simply using your short-hand name, `origin`, plus a slash, in front of their branch names.

Once `git fetch` finishes, your Git now remembers where *their* Git's branch tips were, using *your* `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  You have their commits, plus any required associated stuff so that you can check out those commits and get the files that go with them, but any *new* commits are only going to be *found* via these remote-tracking names.  If they have, as branch tip commits, some of your *older* commits, you might already have other ways to find them.

The counterpart to `git fetch` is `git push`, but it's not completely symmetric.  To do a `git push` to `origin`, for instance, you have your Git call up their Git as before, but this time, you want to *send* them things.  The first part of this sending operation is to hand over any commits that you have, that they don't, that they will need.  You identify these commits by having your `git push` take some extra arguments:

```
git push origin module1:module1
```

Note that I've put in the same name twice here.  The name on the left, the `module1:`, is to find the *specific commit hash* that you want to send to them.  That's the *tip commit* of your `module1`.  The name on the right, the `:module1` part, is the *name you want them to use*.  (These names don't have to be the same!  But it gets tricky if you use different names on each side, so avoid that if possible.)

When you run `git fetch origin`, you generally want to pick up *everything* they have that you don't.  That's quite safe, because whatever tip commit they have as their `master`, your Git will call your `origin/master`.  Whatever tip commit they have as their `module1`, your Git will call that your `origin/module1`.  Your remote-tracking names are your own private entries, all reserved for that one remote named `origin`, and it's harmless, or even a good thing, to just get them all up to date right away.<sup>1</sup>

But `git push` doesn't work this way.  You send them a commit hash ID, and then ask them to set their *branch*, `master` or `module1` or `feature1`, to that hash ID.  They have your Git send the commit object (and as many parent commits and other objects they need, all identified by hash IDs) if they don't already have that commit-ID, and then they evaluate for themselves *whether they will let you set their branch name*.  Sometimes they will, and your push succeeds; sometimes they find a rule that says "don't allow this", and your push fails.

Note that their rules are up to them!  You send a request ("please set your `module1` to `a9fc312...`"); they can look at their current `module1` branch hash ID, and the commit you've sent if it's new, and *choose* whether or not to take the request.  You can use `--force` to send it as a command, but even if you do that, they can still choose whether to obey the command.  All you can do is make a request (or forceful command) and see whether they accept it.  But there's a standard rule that most Gits use most of the time: a request is allowed if the only thing it does is *add new commits*.

Look what happened when you added a commit to `br1` above.  The existing commits, which were all *reachable from* the original tip commit, were still reachable from the new tip commit.  The new commit "grew the branch".  It did not change any of the existing—no new commit *can* ever change any existing commit—but the new commit's parent was the old tip commit.  If we start at the new tip and work backwards, as Git does, we arrive at the old tip.

The same rules work well with `git push`: if the request you send to the other Git will keep all its existing commits reachable from the new branch tip, the other Git will probably allow the request.

Note that we've been using `git push origin module1:module1`, but you suggested that we run:

> ```
> git push origin module1 //Being in feature1 branch
> ```

It doesn't matter which branch we're *in* (or `on`, as `git status` would say `on branch feature1`).  What matters here is the two `module1:module1` parts to the `git push` command.  That tells our Git: use *our* name `module1` to find the commit to push, and ask their Git to set *their* `module1` name.

We didn't give two parts.  We only gave one part.  For `git push`, if you only give one part, Git just assumes you mean "use that same name twice".  So `git push origin module1` means `git push origin module1:module1`, after all.

#### `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by a second Git command

You then asked about this:

> ```
> git pull origin module1 //Being in feature1 branch
> ```

What `git pull` does is simple to describe:

1. It runs `git fetch` with most of the arguments you pass it:

   ```
   git fetch origin module1
   ```
2. If that works, it runs a second Git command, which you pick in advance.  The default command to run is `git merge`.  The exact arguments to this second command depend a little bit on what came in during the `git fetch`, but you still have to pick `git merge` vs `git rebase` *before* you get to see what came in.

We mentioned before that we normally just run `git fetch origin`, which brings over all the names `origin` has, and your Git then renames.  If you run:

```
git fetch origin module1
```

this simply *limits* the fetch: it finds out what they have as their `module1`, brings over the commit(s) by ID if necessary, and then sets your `origin/module1`.<sup>2</sup>  It ignores all their other names.  The `module1` here is a lot like in `git push`, except that if you don't use two names—if you don't write `module1:module1`—your Git will just update your remote-tracking name.  (And you should rarely if ever use two names separated by a colon here.  It does work and can be used for some purposes, but you will need to learn more details.)

During the `git fetch`, it doesn't matter which branch you have checked out.  But the *second* Git command is either `git merge` or `git rebase`, and for these two commands, it *does* matter which branch you have checked out.

The second command that `git pull` runs, runs *without changing the current branch*.  Assuming the second branch is `git merge`, the arguments are:

- the branch tip hash ID<sup>3</sup> obtained from the remote Git, and
- the message "merge branch '*name*' of *url*"

This is a lot like running `git merge origin/name`, though the message is a bit different.

What `git merge` does with this is itself a bit complicated, since `git merge` sometimes does nothing, sometimes does a *fast-forward* instead of merging, sometimes does a real merge, and sometimes has merge conflicts that make the merge stop in the middle and get help from you.  I'll leave all of this to other answers.

Let's summarize here:

- Your `git push` and `git fetch` operations always transfer *whole commits*.  They never work on individual files: they copy *commits* from one Git repository to another.  The process of copying commits normally involves setting some name(s) in the receiving Git, so as to remember any adjusted tip commits.  For the most part, these don't care about your current branch (though `git push` can be told to push the current branch by default: see `push.default`).
- Your `git pull` simply runs two separate Git commands.  If you're not already very familiar with both of those commands, I suggest you run each command separately instead.
- Your `git merge` command is the most complicated one, and should be a separate question.  If you don't think you ran a `git merge` command, see `git pull` above.

---

<sup>1</sup>The one drawback to getting *everything* is that it could take a long time, if there is a lot of "everything" and your net connection is slow.  On the other hand, if you get everything today, you will have almost nothing to get tomorrow, so the *next* `git fetch` will go fast.  If you selectively get just a little today, maybe tomorrow's `git fetch` will be slow.

<sup>2</sup>This assumes your Git version is at least 1.8.4.  In Git before 1.8.4, `git fetch origin module1` brings over their hash ID, but then throws away the name, failing to update your own `origin/module1`.

<sup>3</sup>If you run `git pull origin name1 name2`, Git passes multiple hash IDs to `git merge`, which produces what Git calls an *octopus merge*.  This is almost never what you want, so avoid that.  If you avoid `git pull` you won't make this particular mistake!

Comment: If I could upvote more than once, I definitely would.

Comment: Underrated answer is underrated.

Answer (score 1):

You are broadly correct. I Think following a few tutorials on git branching, or some general experimentation with a simply repository will help solidify your understanding of what's going on in the situations you describe.

For your specific questions, if we assume you've branched twice, and have made no commits:

```
Master  |  A -> B 
--------        ^ 
Module  |       | (B)  
--------        ^ 
Feature |       | (B)
```

Query 1: What if you were working on the `Feature` branch, committed some changes, and pushed them to Module?

So first you made some new commits, let's say 2 additional commits on `Feature`:

```
Master  |  A -> B 
--------        ^ 
Module  |       | (B) 
--------         \
Feature |         C -> D
```

You then pushed that change to `Module`, assuming that no other changes have been committed on Module, you could represent the change graph like so:

```
Master  |  A -> B 
--------         \ 
Module  |         C -> D
--------               ^
Feature |              | (D)
```

Your commits from `Feature` are simply applied on top of the `Module` branch (assuming a fast forward merge); more accurately, the `Module` branch pointer is moved to commit 'D', so it essentially points to the same series of commits as `Feature`. N.B. I'm intentionally not mentioning forcing merge commits, rebasing, or other potential complications.

You then decide that you didn't want those changes on the `Module branch`, the potential complication here is that you used the word `revert`. I believe what you're describing is that you move the `Module` branch pointer back to `B` using `git reset <commit hash for B>`, this essentially [resets](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) your state to the one prior to pushing your changes to `Module`.

```
Master  |  A -> B 
--------        ^ 
Module  |       | (B) 
--------         \
Feature |         C -> D
```

Note, if you actually [reverted](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commits using `git revert <commit hash to revert>`, you would be creating new commits in the `Module` branch, which would undo the introduced changes. I'm reasonably sure this isn't what you're describing.

Query 2: Your understanding is essentially correct.
`git pull` is a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, so it could be considered equivalent to:

```
git fetch origin module1
git merge origin/module1
```

As you correctly state, any changes in `Module` which are not present in your current branch will be merged (N.B. intentionally assuming no rebasing). If there are merge conflicts which git is unable to resolve, you will need to manually resolve the conflicts.

Some handy links:

- https://learngitbranching.js.org/
- https://try.github.io/
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score -1):

The answer for the two queries should be different based on different situations:

#### Situation 1: `feature1` branch is branched off from the latest `module1` branch (no commits made on `module1` branch after created `feature1` branch).

The commit history as below:

```
---A---B---…    master
        \
         C---D---E    module1
                  \
                   F---G---H   feature1
```

- If you push changes to remote `module1` branch from local `feature1` branch, it can let you successful, and `module1` branch in remote repo will point to commit `H`.
- If you pull changes from remote `module1` to local `feature1` branch, it won’t pull any commits to your local `feature1` branch. And it will say already-up-to-date.

#### Situation 2: there has new commits on `module1` branch after branched off `feature1` branch.

The commit history look as below:

```
---A---B---…    master
        \
         C---D---E---I---J    module1
                  \
                   F---G---H   feature1
```

- If you push changes to remote `module1` branch from local `feature1` branch, git will stop pushing and hint you to pull first, since the commit `I` and `J` in above graph are not exist in `feature1` branch.
- If you pull changes from remote `module1` to local `feature1` branch, it will merge the changes from `origin/module1` branch into `feature1` branch (as you thought).

Even pull/push to different branches may work as fast-forward or merge, but **you’d better execute pull/push on it’s own local branch**. It can make the work on different branches more cleanly.